# Need help using LIMIT 1 with the get_where function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to limit 1 row with the get_where function in CodeIgniter 3. For some reason its still returning all the rows.

Does anyone know how I can make this work ? Thanks!

```
 public function getNotes($applicant_id,$client_id,$last_note)
{


    /*The notes are displayed by the applicant id that is passed by the $_GET variable from the Note controller
    But just to be extra safe and make sure only the freelancer who is signed in can view the it will only show if the
    session client id matched the client ID in the db */

    $limit = $last_note == true ? "LIMIT 1" : "";



    $this->db->order_by('client_notes_id', 'DESC');
    $qry = $this->db->get_where("client_notes", ["applicant_id" => $applicant_id, "client_id" => $client_id], $limit);


    try {
        $result = $qry->result();
        return $result;


    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // fb($e->getMessage());
    }


}
```

Comment: Limit is not going to work if there is no ORDERBY clause so add it before limit and then it will work. You cann use ORDERBY with any of your column name.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're doing wrong:

`$limit = $last_note == true ? "LIMIT 1" : "";`

As mentioned on `Query Builder Class` Guide, $limit should be `integer`

try `$limit = 1` instead of `$limit = "LIMIT 1"`

Comment: Thanks a lot! You where right. I also learned that you can just simply do $this->db->limit(1)

Answer (score 0):

From your requirement you can use it three way.But best way is

```
$this->db->from('client_notes');
$this->db->order_by('client_notes_id', 'DESC');
$this->db->where('applicant_id',$applicant_id);
$this->db->where('client_id',$client_id);
if($last_note)
{
    $this->db->limit(1);
}
$qry = $this->db->get();


try {
    $result = $qry->result();
    return $result;


} catch (Exception $e) {
    // fb($e->getMessage());
}
```

others

**way 1.**

```
$limit = $last_note == true ? 1 : NULL;
$this->db->order_by('client_notes_id', 'DESC');
$qry = $this->db->get_where("client_notes", ["applicant_id" => $applicant_id, "client_id" => $client_id], $limit);
```

**way 2**

```
if($last_note)
{
    $this->db->limit(1);
}
$this->db->order_by('client_notes_id', 'DESC');
$qry = $this->db->get_where("client_notes", ["applicant_id" => $applicant_id, "client_id" => $client_id]);
```

**way 3**

```
$this->db->order_by('client_notes_id', 'DESC');
$qry = $this->db->get_where("client_notes", ["applicant_id" => $applicant_id, "client_id" => $client_id]);
try {
    if($last_note)
    {
        $result=$qry->row();//remember it will produce the result differnt way
    }
    else
    {
        $result = $qry->result();
    }
    return $result;
}
```